# I cannot exit a pymsgbox module by clicking the red "X" button

Tags: python, tkinter

I use the pymsgbox (simplified from tkinter) library in one of my programs and created a prompt box. Everything works as expected except for the exit button. Indeed, my red "X" button does not work. When I press it, nothing happens. I use the PyCharm IDE (2019.3) and pymsgbox version 1.0.3.

Here's some sample code that reproduces my issue. It's quite simple.

```
import pymsgbox as pmb

response = pmb.prompt('Prompt', 'Test')
print(response) # When 'X' is clicked, nothing is outputed.
```

Surely something is wrong with my version of pymsgbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: What sort of output do you expect? Normally, clicking the 'x' on a dialog does exactly the same thing as clicking the cancel button. When I run this code from the command line, I get `None` whether I click the cancel button or the "x", which is exactly what should happen. Are you running the code from within pycharm, or from the command line?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've resolved my issue by simply getting the pymsgbox==1.0.7. The newest version.